# Is there any way to get Lubuntu 22.04 to suspend without asking 'If you really want to...'?

Tags: 22.04, lubuntu, suspend

The suspend button in Lubuntu 22.04 desktop asks for confirmation.  I'm going to find that really annoying after a while.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to a similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1272300/how-to-disable-shutdown-confirmation-on-ubuntu-20-04), to suppress the logout confirmation dialog.

```
gsettings get org.gnome.SessionManager logout-prompt
```

default value is true, so you can try to disable it by

```
gsettings set org.gnome.SessionManager logout-prompt false
```

if it doesn't work, set value back to true

```
gsettings set org.gnome.SessionManager logout-prompt true
```

Comment: Thanks.  gsettings did not work, but following the question you linked, I did sudo apt install dconf-editor and tried to navigate to org.gnome.gnome-session > logout-prompt > disable.  However it does not exist in Lubuntu, and I could not find any equivalent.